# Access modal view controller with ios UI Automation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Is there a way to access the elements of an modal view controller with UI Automation. I can't find the view or any elements when printing the tree of the local target. Only the view "behind" is shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: Modal view controllers are not added instantly to the view hierachy. Adding:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().delay(1);
```

before printing the tree solved the problem.